# macOS High Sierra, Messages won't search at all

Tags: messages, spotlight, search, migration

I just got a new 2018 Macbook Pro, so I'm in the process of migrating from my 2013 MBP to the new one.  I don't trust the Migration Assistant due to numerous bad past experiences, so I do this kind of thing manually.

To move my Messages content over, I copied the entire `~/Library/Messages/` directory over to the new machine, and Messages generally seems to work fine - all my messages are there, Text Forwarding from my phone works, etc.  The one thing that doesn't work, is search.  I can't search for *anything* at all, no matter what it is.  100% of attempted searches results in "No Results Found".

Is this a Spotlight issue?  Is there some trick to make Messages' content searchable?

Comment: sounds like moving stuff got lost or it is in wrong place

Comment: what is the date and the size of the ~/Library/Messages/chat.db ? and do you still have the old one ?

Comment: I do still have the old as I merely copied the folder, and have not wiped the old machine yet.  Last Modified local timestamp is, not surprisingly, just a matter of minutes ago - Today (Dec. 24) at 7:59 PM.  chat.db is 274.8 MB

Comment: so it is using the new db (not yours). Rename that file in to newchat.db then copy the old one into the folder named chat.db. Lets see if that works, unless I got the wrong file. Check the 2 other files in that folder, I think the search is using the newer version and can not find anything.

Comment: You lost me... using the "new db"?  The one in use currently started as a copy of the old one (and has since had data added to it as I've been using Messages on this new machine all day).  All message history is intact, everything except search works correctly.  Are you saying you want me to again copy the chat.db file from the old Macbook, into the new one's Messages directory?  Also there is no folder named chat.db, chat.db is a file.

Comment: I suspect the search is looking in to the wrong file

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  What file do you think it's looking into?

Comment: there are 3 files there.chat.db-wall. chat.db and chat.db-shm. I forgot to ask, did you use iCloud.

Comment: That's correct.  Any idea what I can do to attempt to validate your theory and potentially fix the issue?

Comment: I do not know which one is used in search and why that link is broken. Since you still have the copy, delete them all then copy one at time and try.

Comment: No change at all, tried all 3 files individually.  But I noticed one other odd behavior I can't explain.  If I just keep searching for things, it will sometimes work.  But when it does, 100% of the time in my tests it is because the word I searched for is in the name of the contact.  For example searching for "tim" turned up messages from Tim a couple of times (but not every time), searching for other names turned up messages that included those names in the contacts (but again, not every single time). I wonder if maybe Spotlight is busily doing its thing and search will finally work tomorrow?

Comment: it sounds like it is creating new database for the search.

Comment: Well still no search today.  Spotlight is still running... I find it extremely hard to believe it could be taking this long just to build a search DB.  It wouldn't take this long to index my entire hard drive which has a *lot* more content to index.  Something seems to be just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally [got a solution for this in the Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250042726?=undefined&page=1).  Still not sure why it worked but, here's what was suggested:

> In Sys Prefs>Spotlight>Search Results, uncheck "Mail & Messages" (and leave it unchecked), then
>   add your drive to Spotlight's exclusion pane, wait, then remove the
>   drive from the exclusion pane, wait for Spotlight to rebuild it's
>   index.

I had to leave the machine overnight but this morning, Messages search works again.